# Makefile unusual behaviour

Tags: compiling, c++, make, makefile

I have written a make file for a simple cpp program containing `cout` statements.

```
#This a makefile for compiling the hello world cpp program.
   CC=clang++
   all: run test.o 
   run: .cpp=.o
  .PHONY: clean
   clean:
        rm -rf *.o run
```

but this is not compiling my test.cpp. From a tutorial I have taken this idea that `make`  is intelligent enough to compile dependency and target if nothing is specified.

What is going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case there is no need for a makefile, since `make` has built-in rules that know how to compile a simple program.

### Easy way

1. Create a hello world test program named test.cpp.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

   int main() 
   {
       cout << "Hello, World! << endl;
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. Change directories with `cd` to the directory containing test.cpp and run`make`.

   ```
   make CC=g++ test
   ```

   In order to run the above command `make` and `g++` must be installed.
3. Run the test executable.

   ```
   ./test
   ```
4. Results of `./test` :

   ```
   Hello, World!
   ```

### Hard way

1. Create a hello world test program named test.cpp, the same as in the easy way.
2. Change directories with `cd` to the directory containing test.cpp and create a makefile named makefile1.

   ```
   CC      = clang++
   CFLAGS  = -g
   RM      = rm -f

   default: all
   all: Hello
   Hello: test.cpp
       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o Hello test.cpp
   clean veryclean:
       $(RM) Hello
   ```

   The two indented lines must begin with tabs, not 4 spaces. The above makefile will also run correctly if you replace `clang++` with `g++` .
3. Run`make`.

   ```
   make -f makefile1
   ```

   In order to run the above command `make` `clang` and `g++` must be installed.
4. Run the Hello executable.

   ```
   ./Hello
   ```
5. Results of `./Hello` :

   ```
   Hello, World!
   ```

Comment: but what is wrong with my makefile. I want these types of small make files for the testing of small small programs for PoC before going for actual research development projects.

Comment: I rewrote your makefile program so that it works, and added the code of the makefile to my answer. In my makefile there are three variables named CC, CFLAGS and RM.